# Toolbar setOnScrollChangeListener() for api level 19

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-toolbar, android-scroll

Is there any alternate listener which I can use to get scrolling amount in y axis?

I am using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` but it doesn't have backward compatibility to API level 19.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve that using [`ViewTreeObserver#addOnScrollChangedListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#addOnScrollChangedListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener)) API:

```
    toolbar.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
          @Override public void onScrollChanged() {
              int x = toolbar.getScrollX();
              int y = toolbar.getScrollY();
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood properly , you can use `addOnScrollChangedListener()` instead.

Hope this helps.
Sorry for my english.